# Using custom SslStream in WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service through https with client authentication. The code looks like below

```
var webHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
webHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
var webChannelFactory = new WebChannelFactory<MyService>(webHttpBinding, serviceUri);
webChannelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientCertificate;
webChannelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

var service = webChannelFactory.CreateChannel();

service.SomeMethod();
```

The problem with this is, whenever I use some client certificate(from a pfx file) the .NET SslStream expects its signer and root certificate needs to be present in Windows certificate store. If they are not present it doesn't send the client certificate during TLS handshake which results in authentication failure.

I assume this is a behavior of SslStream and can't be changed. If it is true is there a way to use custom SslStream in the above WCF client code? For example OpenSSL.NET provides a SslStream class which doesn't have this limitation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your **clientCertificate** of type **X509Certificate**? In my tests, creating certificate of type **X509Certificate2** helps to use certificate without installing it into Windows storage.

Comment: The **clientCertificate** is type of X509Certificate2. I am passing pfx file name to the X509Certificate2 constructor while creating object of it.